# How to install Realtek Audio Drivers for Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, realtek

I have this issue in my computer:
https://youtu.be/QX-daRypDGY

I had the same issue in Windows but I fixed installing Realtek Audio Codecs (the ones in this page https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software)

But the linux versions of those drivers are outdated and I cannot install them. What should I do?

Comment: What is "this issue"?

Comment: Its exactly what it looks like, the system cannot "decide" what should be the output device and keep switching between both

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  You also haven't explained why you can't install the driver from that site.  The instructions are in the Readme file or the PDF file contained in the `.tar.bz2` file.  Also, the currently installed driver can sometimes show up if you run `sudo lshw -C multimedia`.  The driver from Realtek might possibly be newer and not necessarily outdated.

Comment: @Terrance Kernel drivers well support Realtek devices. The problem may be with some settings specific to this laptop.

Comment: @Pilot6 I will agree on the audio, but I have a RTL8168 that is horribly supported in the Kernel.  I have never had an issue with that network card since I have gone with the drivers from Realtek themselves.  Anyway, OP has missed a lot of info in their question that could help more like you said a specific problem with the laptop.  Or what version of Ubuntu they are running, etc.

Comment: @Terrance Realtek produces very many rtl8168 devices with the same chip name. That is a problem. Kernel developers add new devices, but sometimes they don't do it fast enough. In this case vendor drivers are helpful. personally I never had any problems with `r8169` for a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with Ubuntu 22.04. I had downloaded the latest file from Unix(Linux) file list. After that follow these points which are also provided in pdf inside the downloaded .tar.bz2 file.

1. If your Linux system Playback is no sound output or Recording is failed.
   Please download workarround driver from Realtek website.
   https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software
2. Unzip the driver source code:

   tar jxvpf LinuxPkg_x.xxrcxx.tar.bz2

Dont forget to replace with the file name you have downloaded. And then go inside the extracted folder,

```
cd <folder_extracted>
cd alsa
```

then extract the tar file available in this folder.

```
tar jxvpf alsa-driver-1.0.xx.tar.bz2
cd <extracted_file>
```

replace file name with your tar file.

3. Config compile environment:

   ./configure

This will check your system which compile capabilities is.
If you want to compile the HDA driver part only, please follow.

```
./configure --with-cards=had-intel
```

4. Compile driver source code

   make
5. Install the new driver

   make install

If you get permission error, use "sudo" before 4th and 5th point.

Then restart your system.

This worked for me.

Comment: cp: cannot stat 'snd-hrtimer.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-hwdep.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-page-alloc.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-pcm.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-rawmidi.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-timer.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd.ko': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [/mnt/nas/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-

Comment: Didn't work for me on 22.04, and I also had to install gcc-12 (default for 22.04 was gcc 11).  Looks like that diver source from 2018 finally stopped working with the latest Ubuntu kernel.